# Adding multiple files to attachments using WebClient

Tags: c#

I m trying to send email having multiple attachments from my website dashboard. However, my code is only able to attach the last file. I m using `**WebClient()**` to download files from Cloud system and then adding them as attachments.

This is the code I have written:

```
foreach (var link in attachments)
{
      var uri = new Uri(link);
      var s = uri.Segments[1];

      var tempDirectory = @"c:\tempFolder\" + @"\"+ s;

      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      webClient.DownloadFile(link, tempDirectory);

      Attachment attachment = new Attachment(tempDirectory);
      attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
      attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
      attachment.ContentId = model.Id.ToString();
      attachment.ContentType.Name = s;

      email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDITED:
I attached two files, so getting these links in each loop:

Loop 1:
abc.com/TestEmail1.txt

Loop 2:
abc.com/TestEmail2.txt

Comment: Sholdn't the segment number change for each file? uri.Segments[1]

Comment: No it is not. It will remain the same.

Comment: what happens when you run this code in debug mode stepping thru the loop..? what is the value of var link during each iteration..? can you provide more information in this regard..?

Comment: @MethodMan I have updated my Question.

Comment: also why do you have this `var tempDirectory = @"c:\tempFolder\" + @"\"+ s;` when it appears that all you need to do is the following 
`var tempDirectory = @"c:\tempFolder\" +  s;`

Comment: @MethodMan Lets suppose s = email.txt. If I remove @"\", it is then generating the path as ' c:\tempFolder email.txt 'which is throwing error.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible when you have the `@` literal after the =` sign.. either way.. I would suggest that you down load the attachments first to some local path then once completed add the attachments to the email after downloading from the url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing these lines has solved my problem

```
attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
attachment.ContentId = model.Id.ToString();
attachment.ContentType.Name = s;
```